# Create packages with active_shipping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemerchant

I use active_shipping gem for calculate shipping cost and I have some problem.My package can have several identical objects. I use PackageItem class for these but when I use find_rates method I have this error.

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'inches' for #<ActiveMerchant::Shipping::PackageItem:0x007fec95f24610>`

That is example how I use it:

```
origin = Location.new(country: 'US', zip: '91801')
dest = Location.new(country: 'US', zip: '90001')
packages = PackageItem('test', 32, 18, 15, units: :imperial)
carrier = USPS.new(login: 'LOGIN')
carrier.find_rates(origin, dest, packages)
```

This is initializer for PackageItem:

```
def initialize(name, grams_or_ounces, value, quantity, options = {})
    @name = name

    imperial = (options[:units] == :imperial) ||
      (grams_or_ounces.respond_to?(:unit) && m.unit.to_sym == :imperial)

    @unit_system = imperial ? :imperial : :metric

    @weight = attribute_from_metric_or_imperial(grams_or_ounces, Mass, :grams, :ounces)

    @value = Package.cents_from(value)
    @quantity = quantity > 0 ? quantity : 1

    @sku = options[:sku]
    @hs_code = options[:hs_code]
    @options = options
  end
```

Value is the item cost, thats how I understand this.

If using USPS carrier, the error can make in this place:

```
def self.size_code_for(package)
    if package.inches(:max) <= 12
      'REGULAR'
    else
      'LARGE'
    end
  end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to be using the `Package` module instead of the `PackageItem` module (which doesn't appear to have quantity, so you'll have to duplicate your `Package` objects for higher quantities).

See also this note from the documentation of `PackageItem`: (http://www.rubydoc.info/github/Shopify/active_shipping/ActiveMerchant/Shipping/PackageItem)

> This is only required for shipping methods (label creation) right now.

Comment: If duplicate packages for quantity, calculations of shipping cost return values more expensive than real. Generally building array of packages is bad practice. I implement feature of calculation shiiping cost in web store. I compare response in site with real values in Post. Right (closest to the real) result was obtained when he went 1 package. Its width and height are equal to the width and height of the largest item in the cart, and the depth was calculated as the sum of all the depths of all items from cart.